# PHP/CodeIgniter no POST response from jQuery Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a jQuery Ajax Post request which goes into a Code Igniter function,
after which CodeIgniter sends an email with details in the post request.

## JavaScript Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/admin/index.php/callback',
    data: { 'name': inputName, 'phone': inputNumber},
    success: function() {
        onSuccess();
},
async:true
});
```

## PHP/CodeIgniter function

```
public function email() {
    if (!isset($_POST)) {
         //exit('No direct script access allowed');
    } else {
    //Send Email
    }
}
```

## The Problem SEE EDIT

<del>CodeIgniter does not send a response to the call.</del>

<del>The Post request is recieved and run as the email part works fine, I recieve the email with the details sent in the post request but onSuccess(); is never called (and no response is logged via Chromes network watcher, it just says 'Pending')</del>

This is all ran off my local machine

This request is done from the main index.php BUT CodeIgniter is only installed in the /admin directory

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Changed the ajax url to the full url with localhost as that's how it's set in CI $config

EDIT:
CI does send a response, it takes 2-3 minutes which is also how long it takes the email to be sent, in that time I cannot access any other pages of the site. I am starting to think this may be a problem with my local machine/Apache setup.

Comment: Anything in the PHP error log? The PHP could be exceeding the max time limit and thus producing a `500 internal server error`. Also try on Firebug to see if it hangs with no response like Chrome.

Comment: Ah! I think I found the problem, sendmail fails to send the email, retrys after 1 minute, fails again then retrys again and it works on the third try. I guess I have to sort out CIs email sending/sendmail.

Comment: Also declare the datatype on the ajax request: JSON, text or something else.

Comment: can you add `error:` to your ajax request and pop up an alert. This will prove that the problem is the controller and not `onSuccess();`

Comment: No as I'm stuck with using jQuery 1.4 (I have tested with 1.9 and I had the same issue) the hang comes from PHP waiting for sendmail to send an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my sendmail settings and PHP hanging/retrying until it got a response from sendmail.

Comment: @Sam...I am also facing the same problem..can you tell me what changes you have done??

Comment: It was to do with my fqdn settings as far as I can remember

Answer (score 1):

```
var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url+"index.php/my_class/email",
    data: { name: inputName, phone: inputNumber},
    success: function() {
        // success actions....
    }
});
```

Controller

```
class My_class extends CI_Controller{
    public function email() {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        if (!$name) {
        //exit('No direct script access allowed');
        } else {
        //Send Email
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is the exact same as the base url already (edited my post to note)

Comment: After your edit: My CI Class is constructed correctly, I just ommited everything but the function, everything is called, it just seems to hang for a few minutes when processing the email and not send a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var url = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/my_class/email';

$.post(url, {
    data: { name: inputName, phone: inputNumber},
},
function(data_returned){
    alert(data_returned);
});
```

Comment: I was using post first, there was no change

Answer (score 0):

You should you `empty` instead of `!isset`, because `isset($_POST)` is always `TRUE`, I think so:

```
public function email() {
    if (empty($_POST)) {
         //exit('No direct script access allowed');
    } else {
    //Send Email
    }
}
```